# How to set file but it does not copy or move file into storage?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to save file into the internal or external storage but its not showing to the user in your storage but not a hide folder require. File can not copy or move anywhere in user mobile.

Comment: post what you tried so far ?

Comment: save pdf file in storage but it does not copy file from the phone storage of user.